# Wordpress archive - how to handle just one element of a class for jquery animation?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, this

I have a simple animated corner on wordpress site. This works fine on front-page but on an [archive](http://szmida.nazwa.pl/domliteratury/category/aktualnosci/) page same animation happens on all elements not just current. The code is:

```
//animacja zagiętych rogów
        $(".pad-fix", this).hover(function() {
            console.log('ok');
            $(this).find('.hand').animate({
                borderWidth: "12.5px"
            }, 400);
            $(this).find('.wiecej').animate({
                right: "27px"
            }, 400);
        }, function() {

            $(this).find('.hand').animate({
                borderWidth: "7.5px"
            }, 400);
            $(this).find('.wiecej').animate({
                right: "22px"
            }, 400);
        });
```

How can I cut back on the animation to just one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are hovering over a single article, you are triggering `hover` event on `.pad-fix` element, which appears to be parent of **all** articles on a page. This basically means that `$(this) == $('.pad-fix')` in event handler context. So, the script is trying to find **all** `.hand` elements inside `.pad-fix`, not inside single `.pad-fix article`, which is being hovered. Try to bind your `hover` event to `.pad-fix article` or `.pad-fix .dl_lead`.